# Steam games is not Working on linux

Tags: 12.04, games, steam, crash

**I had this weird error:**

```
OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems. For more information visit https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9938-EYZB-7457.
```

I'm not sure how to fix it as i am fairly new to ubuntu,i am also using a chromebook running ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS,

Comment: is this a arm or x86 chromebook?

Comment: To get the details of your installation type `uname -a` from the terminal.